# clone values of select fields into span or any other html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

this is the fields I have in the app, I need to clone this values into some span elements or any other html elements, so it will be a clone of the date that I select from selectors:

```
<select id="massmedium_register_date_1i" name="massmedium[register_date(1i)]"></select>
<select id="massmedium_register_date_2i" name="massmedium[register_date(2i)]"></select>
<select id="massmedium_register_date_3i" name="massmedium[register_date(3i)]"></select>
```

ex:

I select: `15 - 06 - 1982`

clone to:

```
<span class="date">15</span><span class="date">06</span><span class="date">1982</span>
```

any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried reading [the jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)?

Comment: jQuery? never heard of it.. sure I did and have not found the solution, would be better to get a direct link to the problem itself instead of the link to Docs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538). You should [read the FAQ.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: :) nice page, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: 1. Put some effort into researching the problem, -  oh man I did, 2. Attempted to write some code yourself  - it would take me a day to write the post with all examples I've tried. I am could do this only with jquery datepicker, but the problem is that it needs to be with select fields.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you date

```
var d = $('#massmedium_register_date_1i').val();
```

Then you can write it

```
var span = '<span class="date">' + d +'</span><span class="date">06</span><span class="date">1982</span>
';
```

Than append it

```
$('body').append(span);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var

day = $('#massmedium_register_date_1i').val(),
month = $('#massmedium_register_date_2i').val(),
year = $('#massmedium_register_date_3i').val()

// Then put this inside your event
var markup = '<span class="day">'+ day +'</span>' +
  '<span class="month">'+ month +'</span>' +
  '<span class="year">'+ year +'</span>'

$(markup).appendTo('#yourContainer')
```

Comment: based on you code I have came up with this  http://jsfiddle.net/WTavm/  but it is not quite working as it should be, could you look into it, hopefully you are much better then me in jquery. Thanks.